# Grid Carousel image aspect ratio scaling issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a 1 column/3 rows grid with 3 equal sliders, 1 in each row. Each slider contains the same sized slides.

I set the parent container to 100vh, each child filling up 1/3 of the screen's height, 100% of the screen's width.

What I am struggling with is to keep the images within the containers centered and always fully visible. In essence, I would like to have the sliders fill up the whole width and height of the screen, but the images within the slides always fully visible with a flexible padding left and right. Right now these fill up the full width in each row but only parts of the images are visible height-wise (cropped depending on aspect ratio change)

Here is the code I got so far (the snippet doesn't seem to render right even thought it doesn't give me any console prompts and runs just fine in my editor):

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2793/0346/files/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2793/0346/files/owl.theme.default.min_home_up_6.css">


<style>
.owl-carousel {
width:100%;
}

.grid-1 {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1,1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3,1fr);
}

/* items */

.grid-1 div {
  color: white;
  max-height: calc(100vh /3);
  font-size: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  }

/* specific item styles */

.item-1 {

  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 1;
    width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-2 {

  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
      width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.item-3 {

  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 3 / span 3;
    width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@import "compass/css3";

</style>

</head>
<body>

  <section class="grid-1">
  <div class="item-1">

    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

  <div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></div>

  <div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></div>


  </div>

  </div>
  <div class="item-2">

    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

<div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></div>

<div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></div>

</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-3">

    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

<div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></div>

<div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></div>

</div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>





<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2793/0346/files/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<script>

var someFunction = function(){};

(function() {

$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    center: true,
    items:1,
    loop:true,
    dots: false
})
            })();



someFunction();

</script>

</body>

</html>
```